# in my api request call I always get 401 error no matter how I try it I always end up with the same error

Tags: api, kotlin, retrofit

I always get a 401 unauthorized user error despite I tried to add token manually and to get it from the response

```
here is my retrofit class

object DataRetrofit {
private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor { chain ->
    val original = chain.request()
    val originalHttpUrl = original.url()
    val url = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
            .addQueryParameter("page", "1")
            .build()
    val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8")
            .addHeader("Accept-Language", "ar")
            .addHeader("Authorization","Bearer + ${Constants.token}")
            .url(url)
    val request = requestBuilder.build()
    chain.proceed(request)
}.build()
val instance: DataAPI by lazy {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).client(client).build()
    retrofit.create(DataAPI::class.java)
}
```

}

Comment: the `+` in "Bearer + ${Constants.token}" probably is the problem, remove it and replace it with "Bearer ${Constants.token}"

Comment: still gives me the same error